# Laravel get data from 2 tables where not null

Tags: php, laravel-4, role

I'm trying to get some data from two different tables,

So it does look like this now:

[image: pic 1]

But I don't want the empty fields (Globale-Moderator, Moderator and Proef-Moderator) to be shown. How can I do this whit this code;

Controller:

```
public function ForumTeam()
    {
        $roles = Role::where('id', '>', '4')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return View::make('team')->with('roles', $roles);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="panel-group col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ $role->name }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

          @foreach($role->user as $user)
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <img src="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/public/img/avatar.jpg" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;padding-bottom:5px;" class="img-circle" alt="{{ $user->username }}" width="75" height="75">
              <h4 style="color:{{ $role->colour }};"><strong>{{ $user->username }}</strong></h4>
              <p>{{ $user->usertitle }}</p>
            </li>
          @endforeach

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

So I want to hide the not filled in fields, how should I do dis propperly?

My other option is to show some text inside of the 'empty' field. Like 'There is nobody with this rank'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should be able to use:

```
@foreach($roles as $role)

   @if($role->user != null || !empty($role->user->name))

   @endif

@endforeach
```

You can then check to see if the `role->user` is NOT NULL OR the name of the role is not empty.WHERE `name` is the name of the role, i.e. "Admin", "Moderator"

Alternatively, try:

```
  @foreach($roles as $role)

    @if(count($role->user) >= 1)
       // Do stuff
    @endif

  @endforeach
```

Since you are getting `User` which has a one-to-many relationship, therefore there will be more than one user.

Comment: @RobinR No worries. A tip: If you `dd($roles)` you can see how the data is spread out.. You can then click on relations, see that there are 4, for example and see if they contain empty objects. Thus giving you the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the tip! I didn't thinks so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if statement after the first `@foreach`, to check if the role 
has users,

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
    @if(isset($role->user))
    ...
    @endif
@endforeach
```